# Is it possible to 'prepare' a Propel 1.4 Criteria so it can be used efficiently inside a loop?

Tags: prepared-statement, propel

I'm using symfony 1.3 with Propel 1.4. I need to use a prepared query that will be used inside a loop changing the values of bound parameters.

Is it possible to do this with Propel 1.4? I want to retrieve results as objects so don't want to use raw SQL if I can help it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Propel does not seem to support this out of the box. Take one of the examples, the `Book` class. `BookPeer::doSelect()` calls `BookPeer::doSelectStmt()` and passes the result to `BookPeer::populateObjects()`. `BookPeer::doSelectStmt()` calls [`BasePeer::doSelect()`](http://www.propelorm.org/browser/tags/1.4.2/runtime/classes/propel/util/BasePeer.php#L437), which always calls [`BasePeer::createSelectSql()`](http://www.propelorm.org/browser/tags/1.4.2/runtime/classes/propel/util/BasePeer.php#L745) to create the SQL statement, prepares it, and passes it to [`BasePeer::populateStmtValues()`](http://www.propelorm.org/browser/tags/1.4.2/runtime/classes/propel/util/BasePeer.php#L551) to actually bind the values.

You can take code from these methods to get something like this (without exception or transaction handling):

```
$criteria = new Criteria();
$criteria->addThis();
$criteria->addThat();


$con = Propel::getConnection($criteria->getDbName(), Propel::CONNECTION_READ);
$params = array();
$sql = BasePeer::createSelectSql($criteria, $params);
$stmt = $con->prepare($sql);
// $stmt is a prepared PDOStatement
// $params is an array of the form: [{'table': 'tableName', 'column': 'columnName', 'value': 'paramValue'}, ...]
// You can keep this format and use BasePeer::populateStmtValues(), or you can call $stmt->bindParam() yourself

// Now in the loop, we set the params ourself
foreach ($loop as $loopData) {
    // Bind the params, using your preferred method
    // ...

    // Pass the prepared and bound statement to populateObjects()
    $books = BookPeer::populateObjects($stmt);

    // Do something with the found objects
    // ...
}
```